# iOS6 : NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate: gives incorrect value in iOS 6 only ( different result from previous iOS versions )

Tags: ios6

For the codes below,

```
NSTimeInterval theInterval = [Adate timeintervalSinceDate Bdate];
```

this is the code i am using . in ios 5.0 it is giving me the proper value. But in iOS 6 same code is giving me incorrect value. So i am suspecting `timeIntervalSinceDate` is not working properly in iOS 6.

Why is there a difference between iOS 5 and iOS 6 results ?

**UPDATE**: Same for function `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceNow]`

Comment: I have the same issue. For example, that line of code in iOS 5 provides 207.082923 however in iOS6 it becomes 31622737.127376. Did you find a solution?

Comment: same here. iOS6 is giving incorrect information. Other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637472/ios6-timeinterval-bug) pointed to NSDateFormatter issue, but it is not our case.