# iOS6 TimeInterval bug

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have some code that works perfectly fine in iOS 5, but breaks in iOS 6.

It is the TimeIntervalSinceDate method...

I've found others with this problem, but no solutions:

Here is my code:

```
  NSString *origDate = @"2012-11-29 19:43:30";

   NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *convertedDate = [df dateFromString:origDate];
    [df release];


    NSDate* sourceDate = [NSDate date];

    NSLog(@"sourceDate: %@", sourceDate);
    NSLog(@"convertedDate: %@", convertedDate);

    NSTimeInterval ti = [ sourceDate timeIntervalSinceDate:convertedDate];

    NSLog(@"interval double: %f", ti);
```

In iOS 5, I get this as a value:

```
interval double: 711.113610
```

in iOS 6 I get:

```
interval double: 31623151.242078
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Stop using capital Y's for years. Just don't.

Comment: No need to set the formatter behavior to 10.4. That's the default.

Comment: What is the log output for the two dates?

Comment: It's a difference of 366 days, more or less -- very likely due to the YYYY thing.

Comment: Use timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate on both and do the subtraction yourself.  And NSLog those two dates!!!

Comment: yyyy is the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See what Apple say about [Date Formatters](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html):

> A common mistake is to use
>   YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year
>   (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most
>   cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be
>   different. Typically you should use the calendar year.

Comment: Thank you yyyy (not YYYY) works perfectly in iOS5 and iOS6, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

iOS switched Unicode versions between 5.1 and 6.

iOS 6.0 - use [tr35-25](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) instead of [tr35-19](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: But the above is straight ASCII -- shouldn't care about Unicode.

Comment: The unicode norm tr35-25 and 19 define the Date formatting symbols.